# Leaflet: Set HTML Block like L.ImageOverlay

Tags: html, leaflet

Is it possible to set an layer like imageOverlay with html markup embed in Leaflet map? Maybe with a plugin?
I tried to set it with Popup, but I need more control about the X and Y coordinates. So it isn't a solution for my case.

Comment: Do you need the HTML layer to scale with zoom or not? A small picture would probably help.

Comment: Yes it should be zoomable.

Comment: [Here you can find the example](http://jsfiddle.net/user9090900/3tf7o40u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [Leaflet tutorials](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html) on how to extend Leaflet and make plugins, and have a look at the [source code for `L.ImageOverlay`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/ImageOverlay.js), the answer becomes quite easy:

```
L.HtmlBlockOverlay = L.ImageOverlay.extend({
  initialize: function(bounds, options) {
    return L.ImageOverlay.prototype.initialize.call(this, null, bounds, options);
  },

  _initImage: function() {
    var block = this._image = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-image-layer' +
                                               (this._zoomAnimated ? ' leaflet-zoom-animated' : ''));

    if (this.options.className) { L.DomUtil.addClass(block, this.options.className); }
    block.innerHTML = this.options.html;
  }
});


var blockOverlay = new L.HtmlBlockOverlay(bounds, {
  html: 'Hello world!',
  className: 'hello-world-box'
}).addTo(map);
```

See a [working example](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/defu/edit?html,output).

Comment: Wow I'm very impressed how easy it is. Thank you!

Comment: One question: How can I bind jquery on the created element?
`$('.hello-world-box').on('click', function(){
      console.log('hello');
    });`
doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure that the stuff is in the DOM before attempting to attach events to it.